# Using a logical NOT, !, versus not using it

Tags: c++

I have a function that reads lines from a file and stores each string in each line in a vector.

```
void openf(std::string s)
{
std::string line;
std::string b;
std::ifstream in;
in.open(s);
std::vector<std::string> vec;
if(in.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "File is open\n" << std::endl;
    while(std::getline(in,line)) {
        for(decltype(line.size()) i = 0; i != line.size(); ++i) {
            if(isspace(line[i]) || ispunct(line[i])) {
                vec.push_back(b);
                b = "";
            }
            else {
                b += line[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
for(auto a:vec)
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
in.close();
}
```

This WORKS.

But if instead I do this

```
if(!isspace(line[i]) || !ispunct(line[i])) {
    b += line[i];
}
else {
    vec.push_back(b);
    b = "";
}
```

Nothing prints.

If I don't have the logical OR statements, and just use !isspace and !ispunct individually the program behaves as it expects in the respective cases.

I don't think I am required but I also tried putting () around each operator so it wouldn't interfere with the other each other. Still won't work.

It seems like the same code. Why won't it work in one case and while it works in another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have:

```
if (A || B)
    do this
else
    do that
```

To negate that, you need:

```
if (!(A || B))
    do that
else
    do this
```

And `!(A || B)` works out to `(!A && !B)`

So you need to write

```
if (!isspace(line[i]) && !ispunct(line[i]))
```

See [DeMorgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more info.

Comment: That is too easy to get a +1 (anyway)

Comment: And to think I wasted all that time trying to figure out why thinking it was a syntax problem instead of a logic problem.

Comment: @Comrade - I think you tied yourself into !s thinking about it.

Answer (score 5):

Ref- [De-Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Change `||` to `&&`

`(!A && !B) = !(A || B)`

So use,

```
(!isspace(line[i]) && !ispunct(line[i]))
                   ^^
```

in your second way

Answer (score 3):

That's not the inverse of the condition you're checking in the working code.  This is:

```
if(!isspace(line[i]) && !ispunct(line[i])) {
  b += line[i];
}
else {
  vec.push_back(b);
  b = "";
}
```

`! isspace(x) || ! ispunct(x)` will always be `true`. A space won't be punctuation; puncuation won't be space.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out `!isspace(x) || !ispunct(x)` will always be true.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
if( !(isspace(line[i]) or ispunct(line[i])) )
    b += line[i];
else {
    vec.push_back(b);
    b = "";
}
```

See [this post](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/109100/#msg593927)

Comment: `or`? I think you meant `||`.

Comment: @JimMischel - Not necessarily.  `or` is often defined as a synonym for `||`.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that people often abuse the preprocessor to contort the language into weird shapes. I was just pointing out that `or` is not the standard C++ notation. Those who are not familiar with whatever custom header files you're using won't understand your code. For example, a non-English speaker might not know that `or` is a synonym for `||`.